# FORALL and sql%rowcount when FORALL is never entered

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk-operations

I am curious how you guys deal with the problem that `sql%rowcount` is not set after a `FORALL` that is not entered at all. Example of how I solve it below (using a variable `v_rowcount` and the `count` of the collection the `FORALL` is based on). But I have the feeling that there is a smarter approach:

```
create table tst (id number); -- we start with an empty table

declare
    type type_numbers is table of number;
    v_numbers type_numbers;
    v_rowcount number;
begin

insert into tst values (1);                     
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sql%rowcount); -- prints 1 which is correct, 1 row inserted

delete from tst;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sql%rowcount); -- prints 1 which is correct, 1 row deleted 

v_numbers := type_numbers(3,4,5);
forall v in 1 .. v_numbers.count
    update tst
    set id = v_numbers(v)
    where id = v_numbers(v);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sql%rowcount); -- prints 0 which is correct, 0 rows updated

insert into tst values (1);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sql%rowcount); -- prints 1 which is correct, 1 row inserted

delete from tst;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sql%rowcount); -- prints 1 which is correct, 1 row deleted  

v_numbers := type_numbers();
forall v in 1 .. v_numbers.count
    update tst
    set id = v_numbers(v)
    where id = v_numbers(v);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sql%rowcount); -- prints 1 which is WRONG, 0 rows updated (this is still the sql%rowcount of the DELETE above)

forall v in 1 .. v_numbers.count
    update tst
    set id = v_numbers(v)
    where id = v_numbers(v);
v_rowcount := 0;
if v_numbers.count > 0 then
    v_rowcount := sql%rowcount;
end if;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_rowcount);   -- prints 0 which is correct, 0 rows updated

end;
/
```

Comment: `sql%rowcount` is the result of last dml. you update in a forall Loop was not executed, so `sql%rowcount` Shows the result of your delete Statement. whats wrong?

Comment: @hotfix thank you. nothing wrong. I am just curious on how to nicely deal with this scenario. my solution with the `if v_numbers.count > 0 then` seems clumsy to me and might even produce wrong results (can't think of a case).

Comment: I do not quite understand what the problem is. why not to check if the collection is empty before?

Comment: @hotfix that's exactly my problem/question :-) what is the best practice here? is the best practice to check the count of the collection before the forall?

Comment: @apc just tried it in *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=223ff87dd2dbc8a0eb13b726083e207e)* and i don't see a mystery.

Comment: Why not just add a check to see if v_numbers.count is > 0, and if so return the sql%rowcount, otherwise return 0?

Comment: @hotfix - yeah, EBKAC.

Comment: @Boneist this is what I am doing, see example above. But I was wondering if this is best practice here as it felt weird 'inventing' this myself for such a standard 'problem' like getting the rowcount after a forall.

Comment: It's pretty much the only way to handle this. Your update (as hotfix has already said) isn't being run at all, so sql%rowcount won't reflect anything related to it. You need to have a check that says, in effect, "if the statement didn't get run, return 0, otherwise return sql%rowcount". It's a pretty standard check in this situation afaik.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it as in your example, but there is also alternative. We can use `sql%bulk_rowcount` which may be better for `forall`. Here is a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#i49056) to Oracle documentation and some examples. And this is my test table:

```
create table test (id, val) as (
  select 1, 'PQR' from dual union all
  select 2, 'AB1' from dual union all
  select 2, 'AB2' from dual union all
  select 3, 'XYZ' from dual );
```

and sample code block, where I used short function summing `bulk_rowcount`s:

```
declare 
    type t is table of number;
    a t;

    function bulkcount(x in t) return number is 
      ret number := 0;
    begin
      for i in 1..x.count loop
        ret := ret + sql%bulk_rowcount(i);
      end loop;
      return ret;
    end bulkcount;
begin
    a := t(2, 3, 7);
    forall i in a.first..a.last 
        delete from test where id = a(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('sql rowcount: '||sql%rowcount);
    dbms_output.put_line('sum of bull_rowcount: '||bulkcount(a));

    a := t();
    forall i in a.first..a.last
        update test set val = 'ZZZ' where id = a(i);

    dbms_output.put_line('sql rowcount: '||sql%rowcount);
    dbms_output.put_line('sum of bull_rowcount: '||bulkcount(a));
end;
```

Result:

```
sql rowcount: 3
sum of bull_rowcount: 3
sql rowcount: 3          -- "wrong", value from previous DML
sum of bull_rowcount: 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand that you would go the same way as in my example. Like you, I also think that `bulk_rowcount` is an overkill for my example, especially as it does the exact same thing as my example for empty collections `ret number := 0; [...] for i in 1..x.count loop [... loop not entered...]  end loop; return ret;` to me is equivalent to what I do `v_rowcount := 0; if v_numbers.count > 0 then [... not entered ...] end if; DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_rowcount);` Both versions return the number 0 if the collection is empty, without checking any sql% parameters.

Comment: Yes. `bulk_rowcount` is interesting alternative which allows you to find number of affected rows for each element of collection what is not possible with `rowcount` and `forall`. But here I would use yours version.

Answer (score 1):

SQL%ROWCOUNT works with FORALL

See the example below:

```
-- Data preparation

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
    EMPID     NUMBER,
    EMPNAME   VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    1,
    'a'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    2,
    'b'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    3,
    'c'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    4,
    'a'
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES (
    5,
    'e'
);

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

[image: Before update]

```
-- FORALL update in the block

SET SERVEROUT ON

DECLARE
    TYPE T_BULK_COLLECT_TEST IS
        TABLE OF EMPLOYEES%ROWTYPE;
    L_TAB   T_BULK_COLLECT_TEST;
    CURSOR C_DATA IS
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        EMPLOYEES;

BEGIN
    OPEN C_DATA;
    FETCH C_DATA BULK COLLECT INTO L_TAB;
    FORALL I IN 1..L_TAB.COUNT
        UPDATE EMPLOYEES
        SET
            EMPNAME = L_TAB(I).EMPNAME || L_TAB(I).EMPNAME
        WHERE
            EMPID = L_TAB(I).EMPID;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1) SQL%ROWCOUNT IS ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    CLOSE C_DATA;

    DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2) SQL%ROWCOUNT IS ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    COMMIT;

    OPEN C_DATA;
    FETCH C_DATA BULK COLLECT INTO L_TAB;
    FORALL I IN 1..L_TAB.COUNT
        UPDATE EMPLOYEES
        SET
            EMPNAME = L_TAB(I).EMPNAME || L_TAB(I).EMPNAME
        WHERE
            EMPID = L_TAB(I).EMPID;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('3) SQL%ROWCOUNT IS ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    CLOSE C_DATA;
END;
/
```

[image: SERVER OUTPUT]

```
-- Output after data is updated
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

[image: Data after update]

So as per my example, It is storing a number of rows affected in SQL%ROWCOUNT even if we are using FORALL. ---- BUT BUT BUT, If I remove 'COMMIT' after 'DELETE' statement then I am also facing the same issue as described by you.

So the solution to your problem is `COMMIT` statement. Try to run your code with commit statement just after delete.

Hope, This is useful to you.

**Updated**

```
BEGIN
    OPEN C_DATA;
    FETCH C_DATA BULK COLLECT INTO L_TAB;
    FORALL I IN 1..L_TAB.COUNT
        UPDATE EMPLOYEES
        SET
            EMPNAME = L_TAB(I).EMPNAME || L_TAB(I).EMPNAME
        WHERE
            EMPID = L_TAB(I).EMPID;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1) SQL%ROWCOUNT IS ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    CLOSE C_DATA;

    DELETE FROM EMPLOYEES;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2) SQL%ROWCOUNT IS ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    SAVEPOINT A; --- IMP

    OPEN C_DATA;
    FETCH C_DATA BULK COLLECT INTO L_TAB;
    FORALL I IN 1..L_TAB.COUNT
        UPDATE EMPLOYEES
        SET
            EMPNAME = L_TAB(I).EMPNAME || L_TAB(I).EMPNAME
        WHERE
            EMPID = L_TAB(I).EMPID;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('3) SQL%ROWCOUNT IS ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
    CLOSE C_DATA;
END;
/
```

Comment: hi thanks. yes sql%rowcount works with FORALL, but ONLY IF the pl/sql collection is not empty.  In your example l_tab contains 5 objects. In my example the collection contains no objects and hence sql%rowcount is not set. My question is about how dealing with sql%rowcount after a FORALL where the collection is empty. See my example. ty. kr

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your requirement. Please check and test with your code.

Comment: thank you, but I don't want to commit just for the sql%rowcount to be correct :-)

Comment: Perfect, I am just explaining why it is not working. and the solution was given if useful to you.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Just use `SAVEPOINT`. No need of `COMMIT`. It will work.

Comment: Please refer: [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_sparse.htm)  -- **SQL%ROWCOUNT**:  Refers to the total number of rows affected by the whole bulk operation.  It is the sum of the SQL%BULK_ROWCOUNT values.

Comment: thank you very much for the smart idea with the `savepoint`. Works like a charm. But even when I call the savepoint `reset_sql_rowcount` (the shortest self explanatory I could come up with is 35 chars so too long `ResetSqlRowcountIfForallNotEntered`), I feel that the code needs an additional comment to explain why the savepoint is there so that the next person that reads/changes the code understands it. So I think I still prefer the solutions without a savepoint, as they seems more likely that the reader of the code understands what is going on in the code.